# sqlalchemy constraint in models inheritance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two simple models:

```
class Message(Backend.instance().get_base()):
    __tablename__ = 'messages'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    sender_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id')) 
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)


class ChatMessage(Message):
    __tablename__ = 'chat_messages'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('messages.id'), primary_key=True)
    receiver_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

How to define constraint sender_id!=receiver_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to work with joined table inheritance, I've tried and it complains that the column `sender_id` from `Message` doesn't exist when creating the constraint in `ChatMessage`.

This complaint makes sense, since `sender_id` wouldn't be in the same table as `receiver_id` when the tables are created, so the foreign key relationship would need to be followed to check the constraint.

One option is to make `ChatMessage` a single table.

Use `CheckConstraint`, placed in table args.

```
class ChatMessage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'chat_messages'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sender_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(User.id))
    receiver_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(User.id))
    content = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        sa.CheckConstraint(receiver_id != sender_id),
    )
```